converting a word file into a pdf file without notes
I want to convert a word file into a pdf file using python, but without any notes that I added to the word file.
    for paragraph in infile.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            if run.comment:
                run.clear()  

The above codes didn't work.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Pypdf does not support word 2 pdf Generation. Please share a minimal complete example.
